# How do I change this custom checkmark color in mobile Safari in iOS 10.3.3?

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari

It works in Chrome, but it always shows up black in Safari. I even put `color: #0A0` in 4 different places, and tried `!important`.

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

iPhone

[image]

```css
  /* Customize the label (the container) */
  .checkbox-label {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    color: #0A0;
  }

  /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
  .checkbox-label input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  /* Create a custom checkbox */
  .checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 1px solid goldenrod;
    color: #0A0;
  }

  /* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
  /* Style the checkmark/indicator */
  .checkmark:after {
    content: '\2714';
    display: none;
   font-size: 36px;
    margin: -15px 0 0 0;
    color: #0A0;
    // color: red;
  }

  /* Show the checkmark when checked */
  .checkbox-label input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
    color: #0A0 !important;
  }
```

```html
<label class="checkbox-label">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

iOS 10.3.3, Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181

Comment: You have the wrong image for the iPhone version.

Comment: Haha... apparently "Run Code Snippet" isn't available on the mobile site. Now it points to JS bin with a direct mobile preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo (preview on iPhone):

[image: Demo url]

You need to add [variation selector-15 (U+FE0E)](http://graphemica.com/FE0E) to fix this issue

Change `content: '\2714';` to `content: '\2714\fe0e';`

```css
/* Customize the label (the container) */
  .checkbox-label {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    color: #0A0;
  }

  /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
  .checkbox-label input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  /* Create a custom checkbox */
  .checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 1px solid goldenrod;
    color: #0A0;
  }

  /* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
  /* Style the checkmark/indicator */
  .checkmark:after {
    content: '\2714\fe0e';
    display: none;
   font-size: 36px;
    margin: -15px 0 0 0;
    color: #0A0;
    // color: red;
  }

  /* Show the checkmark when checked */
  .checkbox-label input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
    color: #0A0 !important;
  }
```

```html
<label class="checkbox-label">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: I never would have guessed that. What is a 'variation selector'?

Comment: OK but I still don't get it. The mark looks exactly the same. It's its own character and shouldn't need a variation like an umlaut or accent, etc.

Comment: How can I change it's color, like to red or white?

Comment: @Mohit Change color here `.checkbox-label input:checked ~ .checkmark:after`

Comment: @RajenderJoshi Thank you Rajender for quick response. Your code works but not in Opera, that was the problem earlier and still is. May be it's a bug. I would report it. Anyway. Your answer is correct and works in chrome. Going to accept your answer as correct. Thanks again for sharing.